# how to subset dataframe from first row to the highest value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subset a dataframe based on a column with cumulative values (the column "value").
My dummy dataframe is:

```
index  x         y   g1 g2     value
0      24.25  50.65  a  1        25  
1      24.25  50.65  a  1        28
2      24.25  50.65  a  1       29
3      24.25  50.65  a  1       29
4      24.25  50.65  a  1       29
5      24.25  50.65  b  1       3
6      24.25  50.65  b  1       4
7      24.25  50.65  b  1       5
8      24.25  50.65  b  1       5
```

expected output:

```
index  x         y   g1  g2     value
0      24.25  50.65  a  1        25  
1      24.25  50.65  a  1        28
2      24.25  50.65  a  1       29
3      24.25  50.65  b  1       3
4      24.25  50.65  b  1       4
5      24.25  50.65  b  1       5
```

I have already tried:

```
n=1
df_sub= df[df.groupby(['x','y','g1', 'g2']).apply(
                                lambda x: x.nlargest(n, 'value', keep='first')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it does not keep the rows with values lower than maximum. As far as I know, if you change n to higher values you will get nth highest values but the point is that I have no idea about the range between the first row and the highest value of value.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Omid.

Comment: You’re asking how to remove lines with repeated values in column `value`, is that correct?

Comment: At the moment it looks like `df.drop_duplicates()`? Are there different conditions not expressed here?

Comment: Thanks for your clues. I did not look at this problem from this point of view. I will try your hints and let you know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach, filtering where `value` is the max per group ([`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform)) or not duplicated ([`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas-series-duplicated)):

```
max_m = (
    df.groupby(['x', 'y', 'g1', 'g2'])['value']
        .transform('max')
        .ne(df['value'])
)
dup_m = ~df['value'].duplicated()
filtered_df = df[max_m | dup_m]
```

`filtered_df`:

```
       x      y g1  g2  value
0  24.25  50.65  a   1     25
1  24.25  50.65  a   1     28
2  24.25  50.65  a   1     29
5  24.25  50.65  b   1      3
6  24.25  50.65  b   1      4
7  24.25  50.65  b   1      5
```

---

The benefit of this approach is that it will only remove duplicated maximums not other duplicates and order of the frame does not matter:

`df`:

```
       x      y g1  g2  value
0  24.25  50.65  a   1     25
1  24.25  50.65  a   1     29  # Max
2  24.25  50.65  a   1     25  # Duplicated but not Max
3  24.25  50.65  a   1     28
4  24.25  50.65  a   1     29  # Max (2)
5  24.25  50.65  b   1      3
6  24.25  50.65  b   1      4
7  24.25  50.65  b   1      5
8  24.25  50.65  b   1      5
```

`filtered_df`:

```
       x      y g1  g2  value
0  24.25  50.65  a   1     25
1  24.25  50.65  a   1     29  # First Max is kept
2  24.25  50.65  a   1     25  # Duplicated but not Max (kept)
3  24.25  50.65  a   1     28
5  24.25  50.65  b   1      3
6  24.25  50.65  b   1      4
7  24.25  50.65  b   1      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for [df.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) ?

With `subset` you can specify on which columns to operate, and with `keep` which rows to keep.

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value'], keep='first')
   index      x      y g1  g2  value
0      0  24.25  50.65  a   1     25
1      1  24.25  50.65  a   1     28
2      2  24.25  50.65  a   1     29
5      5  24.25  50.65  b   1      3
6      6  24.25  50.65  b   1      4
7      7  24.25  50.65  b   1      5
```

Comment: I don't know subsetting `value` is the right approach since OP tried groupby on `['x','y','g1', 'g2']`

Comment: Should not I first sort (by groupeby or sort) the dataframe?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re trying to achieve @SeyedOmidNabavi. At the moment it seems to me this solves your problem − it certainly solves your example. You could remove the `subset` argument and it will remove only lines that are fully the same. Otherwise try and add some details into your question